# subscription failure of Observables request from common Layout component in angularjs 4

Tags: angular

My Layout  is:

sidebar

router-oulet

footer

My service code is:

```
private mysubject = new Subject<object>();

    mysubject$ = this.mysubject.asObservable();

  SetUser() {

      this.currentuser = JSON.parse(this.storage.retrieve('currentUser')); 
      this.mysubject.next(this.currentuser);  

    }
```

My Sidebar Component Typescript  code is:

```
constructor(public dataService: DataService) 


{ 


this.dataService.mysubject$.subscribe(user => {

this.loggeduser = user;

alert("SIDE BAR>>>>");


 });


  this.dataService.SetUser();


  }
```

Profile Component ts code is:

```
this.dataService.mysubject$.subscribe(user => {

this.loggeduser = user;

 alert("PROFILE>>>>");

 });


this.dataService.SetUser();
```

Initial time both component  subscription  has called successfully.

But When I have updated the user information  from profile component

```
this.loggeduser=JSON.parse(this.storage.retrieve('currentUser'))

this.dataService.SetUser();
```

Then only Profile component subscription has called but sidebar component subscription  is not called

Comment: The dataService...where are you registering this service i.e where are you assigning this class in providers ?

Comment: I have registered on app.module.ts,also sidebar component and Profile component.